# Dockerfile build fails when running mkdir only for particular locations

Tags: git, jenkins, git-checkout

Our application is a set of docker containers, my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
MAINTAINER xyz
RUN mkdir -p /opt/service
WORKDIR /opt/service
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
COPY package.json /opt/service
COPY package-lock.json /opt/service
RUN npm install
COPY . /opt/service
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Location 1: myproject/jenkins/dockerfile - **it fails to perform mkdir**

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/service’: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /opt/service' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Location 2: myproject/frontend/dockerfile - **the same copy of docker file builds well**

My docker-compose file ends with:

```
app:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: jenkins/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Location 1 gives the expected result and I don't see why location 2 could build successfully.

The default user using jenkins/jenkins:lts image is *jenkins*, who DOES NOT have privilege to create folder at */opt* .

I launched the a jenkins/jenkins:lts container and ran the same command:

```
jenkins@b4890ac012a6:/$ mkdir -p /opt/service
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/service’: Permission denied

# Equivalently
jenkins@b4890ac012a6:/opt$ mkdir service
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘service’: Permission denied
```

To solve this, you need to either switch to USER *root* to create the directory first:

```
....
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/service
USER jenkins
....
```

Or you can pick a path that *jenkins* has executable permission.

Comment: when i used USER root in my dockerfile it worked well. I was able to create a directory with mkdir

Comment: Good to know, does this answer your question? If it helped please mark this as accepted answer.